# itextsharp pdf page border?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using itext sharp for creating reports in PDF format.
I want page borders. I tried some ways. I am not successful.
How can I get a page border for top, bottom, left, right using `iText for .NET`?
I added one image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFyBp.png). I want borders like described in the image.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot find the image you added. Can you add it again?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code for adding the image for the header manually.

//Step 1: Add the Image file

```
strImgPath is refer the directory Info..

Image imgLogo = Image.GetInstance(strImgPath.ToString()+"\\abcdur compe.Jpg");
imgLogo.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
imgLogo.ScalePercent(50f);
```

// Step 2:

```
Add this ImgLogo to the PdfPTable by use of this
PdfPCell pdfcellImage = new PdfPCell(imgLogo, true);
pdfcellImage.FixedHeight = 40f;
pdfcellImage.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfcellImage.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfcellImage.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
pdfcellImage.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
pdftblImage.AddCell(pdfcellImage);
```

// Step 3:

```
Create Chunck to add Text for address or others
fntBoldComHd is a Base Font Library Object

Chunk chnCompany = new Chunk("Your CompanyName\nAddress", fntBoldComHd);

//Step 4:

Create Phrase For add the Chunks and PdfPTables

Phrase phHeader = new Phrase(); 

phHeader.Add(pdftblImage);
phHeader.Add(chnCompany);
```

// Step 5:

```
Assign the Phrase to PDF Header
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(phHeader, false);
header.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
docPDF.Header = header;
```

Comment: Thanks. its working. Can u tell me the for entire pdf border?

Comment: Hope this may help you... http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/89/iTextSharp-Page-Layout-with-Columns

Comment: then try manually adding the rectangle like a border.. that may help

Answer (score 1):

I am using one hacky way of workaround but it will create the border.Use this method.

```
private void CreateBorder(PdfContentByte cb, PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = doc.PageSize;
        float left = r.Left + 30;
        float right = r.Right - 30;
        float top = r.Top - 30;
        float bottom = r.Bottom + 30;
        float width = right - left;
        float height = top - bottom;

        PdfPTable tab = new PdfPTable(1);
        tab.TotalWidth = width;
        tab.LockedWidth = true;

        PdfPCell t = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Empty));
        t.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(250, 235, 215);
        t.FixedHeight = height;
        t.BorderWidth = 3;
        tab.AddCell(t);
        Paragraph pa = new Paragraph();
        pa.Add(tab);

        float h = tab.TotalHeight;
        PdfTemplate temp = cb.CreateTemplate(tab.TotalWidth, h);
        tab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0.0F, h, temp);
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(temp);
        img.SetAbsolutePosition(30, 30);
        cb.AddImage(img);
    }
```

If u want one more section for header create table width two rows.I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the document margins? If yes, use the Document object's ctor to specify them:

```
public Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom);
```